# How can I make breadcrumbs without a full, yeast-leavened loaf of bread?

Tags: substitutions, breadcrumbs

What's the best (fastest, most efficient) way to make breadcrumbs from scratch, without having any old bread?

I'm curious if there's something quick I can do, when I realize I want 5 cups of breadcrumbs and have no old bread, and don't want to buy or bake a loaf of bread just to immediately pulverize it.

That is, what is the fastest, simplest, easiest bread-like thing one could make, which would turn into breadcrumbs in a food processor?

One more edit: I didn't really intend this to be asking "what other ready-made things can I buy (or have around) and turn into breadcrumb substitutes". I want to know, at the very least, the best way to streamline the process of making and drying bread given the fact that I don't care if it's ever moist enough to eat as bread, and don't care about its overall shape or texture or anything else we usually care about in bread.

Comment: I am confused - you want to make bread crumbs without first making or buying bread? So are you looking for an alternate ingredient from which to make breadcrumbs?

Comment: @Katey: Surely breadcrumbs do not require a full loaf of bread. You don't really care much about structure. I imagine you could get away with some sort of quickly thrown-together flatbread with minimal leavening (possibly just steam), rather than taking all the time to make a normal bread with yeast.

Comment: I somewhat suspect that anything you could make that would approximate bread crumbs when processed would be more expensive and time consuming to make than actual bread. We'll see what kind of answers arrive, anyhow...

Comment: @Aaronut: Yeah, I don't know how answerable it is - maybe a quick soda bread, baked fairly thin to minimize baking time, is about the best one can do.

Comment: @Jefromi No, they don't require a full loaf of bread, just some toasted pieces or hunks. I guess I am just not sure why you don't also want the leftover bread that would result from baking or buying a full loaf of bread. Substitutes (which is not what it seemed like you were asking) are going to be your best non-bread solution.

Comment: @Katey: Well, I thought I'd at least ask. Baking a regular loaf of bread isn't exactly instant, and I do like to do things myself! (Plus, fresh bread takes some drying out, so if you baked something that was most of the way there already...)

Comment: @Jefromi, When you present your question as `I'm curious if there's something quick I can do, when I realize I want 5 cups of breadcrumbs and have no old bread, and don't want to buy or bake a loaf of bread just to immediately pulverize it.` You are presenting a "substitution scenario". This notion of "how do I make breadcrumbs without bread" is non-sense.

Comment: Given your edits, sounds like you mean "breadcrumbs without *a full yeast risen loaf of* bread".  You want breadcrumb consistency, but a faster way to do it. I think its a great thing to ask.  (I also think some substitutes like in @Cos's answer are great as well.)

Comment: @rfusca: I've edited my title. That said, I thought it was entirely clear from the body of the question that I didn't mean I wanted to create breadcrumbs out of thin air, or out of a rutabaga.

Comment: So you want to "Bake" Something, but not bread, and end up with Bread Crumbs?

Comment: The indirect question would be whether commercially made breadcrumbs are baked as bread or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dry biscuits (American 'biscuits' - not cookies), or anything other flour based quick bread that dried out - if you're trying to replicate the *bread* crumbs.  You may be able to get by with a modified muffin recipe as well. You'll want to avoid fats and oils to reduce the moistness.

Yeast bread develops a particular flavor and larger hole structure than quick bread though.  The flavor of a quick bread breadcrumbs should be slightly different, but in many dishes the subtle difference won't be overwhelming unless the breading is a 'star' of the dish.  The hole structure really doesn't matter luckily - as developing that is a large part of the time factor of real bread.

Drying it out will be the harder part.  The denser structure holds moisture better, so slice it thin and give it low, dry, long heat.

<sub>Personally, anything that you're going to *make* for the purpose of breadcrumbs that isn't just a substitute (like cereal, crackers, etc in the other answer), sounds like it'd be easier just to make a loaf of fast rise bread to me.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Three substitutes come to mind:

1. Saltine Crackers
2. Pretzels
3. Select brands of Cereal (Chex, Corn Flakes, etc.)

Take these for a spin in your food processor till you reach the consistency you desire.

Depending on your ultimate goal one or any of these could serve as a suitable sub for "bread crumbs"

Comment: I'd also add that pita chips would be a solid option, if you have them lying around.

Comment: Good point @Katey... though Pita chips are not commonly lying around at my place...

Comment: For a zero carb recipe you can use pork rinds as well

Comment: @lazo: I don't know whether to be disgusted by the fact that it's pork rind breading, or disgusted by the fact I didn't think of it first.

Comment: I like rice krispies myself. The poor mans panko breadcrumb. I'd also expand the cracker selection: I've made bread crumbs out of damn near every cracker in existence. If it's crunchy, it'll do.

Comment: Rice Krispies would definitely fit under "Select Cereals" where pork rinds as breading is just plain disgusting. Tried it back when I was doing the Adkins diet. YUCK!Ya, sure it is 'zero carb' and negative flavor.

Comment: The portion of your answer that actually sort of fits my question is crackers: those could be much faster to make than bread, and wouldn't need to be dried out additionally to easily process.

Answer (score 3):

Hardtack.  Or any other kind of plain, baked cracker.

[Hardtack](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Hardtack) is baked from a simple dough made with flour, water, and salt.  It is rolled out, and baked till brown into a kind of cracker.  It is often twice baked, to remove all moisture for long term storage - depending on the moisture of the dough, how thickly it's rolled, and the kind of breadcrumb you need, this might not be necessary, or might be helpful.  Many are rolled thicker and baked longer if they're intended for storage - but if you roll it [quite thin,](http://grandarmyofthefrontier.org/articles/hardtack.htm) like a cracker it will bake quickly to the right texture, and if it's dry it should crumble easily into something like breadcrumbs.

Alternatively, you can pick any recipe for dry crackers or plain unleavened biscuits (think [European style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biscuit), not American).  Hardtack is the simplest of these types of recipes, but some have more ingredients ([sugar, salt, oil](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-crackers-at-home-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-186144)) if you want a bit more flavor in your breadcrumbs, or if you want to use a [little leavening](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/food/homemade-crackers-in-no-time-flat/2013/04/08/704380c0-9bd1-11e2-a941-a19bce7af755_story.html) you should end up with a lighter texture.

The crumbs you get will be similar in texture to using saltines or pretzels, a little bit hard, dense, plain.  But they'll work pretty well for most recipes, and you can make them with whatever flour you've got at hand.  They're also pretty quick to make and very simple - one of the cracker recipes quoted a half to three quarters of an hour for a batch.  One of the hardtack recipes suggested baking times of as little as 5 min per batch (depending on [how thin it is](https://www.lds.org/friend/1975/07/pioneer-recipes?lang=eng)), and the mixing time of the simpler version is not much more.  Since they're already dry and hard, and need very little extra processing (~45 seconds with a mortar and pestle per mortar volume) I expect you'd have your 5 cups of breadcrumbs ready within 45 minutes of starting your recipe.

You might also get away with a simple [bannock](http://www.food.com/recipe/bannock-60224) or flatbread, with the dough rolled very thin and pan toasted until crisp and dry.  It depends on whether toasting them singly on the pan is quicker than all at once in the oven.  These will tend to be softer, usually with a bit more fat ([oil or butter](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/6919/bannock/)) and may include more breadlike flavors (including [yeast](http://www.yummly.com/recipe/external/Homemade-Flat-Bread-1695669)).  The better flavor profile may be worth the extra time drying, depending on the recipe.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of years ago I started an apprenticeship and studied at Tafe.
One of the first things I learnt was how to crumb a chicken schnitzel with Panko bread crumbs. I am frustrated with myself for loosing my recipe but you can make them without a loaf of bread.  Not sure of the ingredients exactly but we used flour and seasoning of choice and and added butter while rubbing the mix gently between the fingers until we had a soft dry mix.

Comment: Interesting, it sounds like a savory streusel? I will have to try this...